# Java Logic Issue Returning All Objects

Tags: java, methods, boolean, logic, increment

I am really new to Java and I am having a problem figuring out why the code below is returning all of the objects, instead of the two objects that fit the search criteria. I'm guessing that it is something in my boolean method but can't seem to determine what it is. Or is it related to my count increment?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestApartment
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Variables to hold input
        int bedrooms;
        double bathrooms;
        int rent;

        // This creates five different 
        // Apartment objects
        Apartment aptOne = new Apartment(101, 2, 1, 725);
        Apartment aptTwo = new Apartment(102, 2, 1.5, 775);
        Apartment aptThree = new Apartment(103, 3, 2, 870);
        Apartment aptFour = new Apartment(104, 3, 2.5, 960);
        Apartment aptFive = new Apartment(105, 3, 3, 1100);

        // Uses Scanner class to accept keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt user for input for minimum number of bedrooms required    
        System.out.print("Enter the minimum number of bedrooms: ");
        bedrooms = keyboard.nextInt();
        // Prompt user for input for minimum number of bathrooms required
        System.out.print("Enter the minimum number of bathrooms: ");
        bathrooms = keyboard.nextDouble();
        // Prompt user for input for maximum amount of rent
        System.out.print("Enter the maximum amount of rent: ");
        rent = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The following apartments match your search: ");

        displayMatch(aptOne);
        displayMatch(aptTwo);
        displayMatch(aptThree);
        displayMatch(aptFour);
        displayMatch(aptFive);

    }

    public static boolean isMatched(Apartment apt, int bedrooms, double bathrooms, int rent)
    {
        int count = 0;
        boolean isMatch;
        final int MIN_MATCH  = 3;

        if (apt.getnumBedrooms() >= bedrooms);
        count = count + 1;
        if (apt.getnumBathrooms() >= bathrooms);
        count = count + 1;
        if (apt.getAptRent() <= rent);
        count = count + 1;
        if(count >= MIN_MATCH)
            isMatch = true;
        else
            isMatch = false;
        System.out.println ("No matches were found.");
        return isMatch;

    }

    public static void displayMatch(Apartment apt)
    {
        // Display the matching apartments

        System.out.println("Apartment Number: "  + apt.getApartment());
        System.out.println("Number of Bedrooms: " + apt.getnumBedrooms());
        System.out.println("Number of Bathrooms: " + apt.getnumBathrooms());
        System.out.println("Rent Amount: $" + apt.getAptRent());
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually called your boolean method anywhere, and call displayMatch on all of your Apartments without checking if they actually match.

Comment: You never call isMatched anywhere. Your code displays every appartment, without filtering anything.

Comment: This would have been really, really easy to find out by yourself, by just executing your code step by step using your debugger, or just adding System.out.println() calls in the methods. Learn to debug your code yourself.